# Find P(A) from the following information...

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let,

P(B and Complement of A)=0.1
P(B)=0.3
P(A and Complement of B)=0.2

The value of P(A) is closest to:

(a) 0.1   (b) 0.2   (c) 0.3   (d) 0.4   (e) 0.5

I've tried to solve this question many different ways, and just can't find a way

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include in the body of the question your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only events $A$ and $B$, you can solve by thinking graphically.
$P(B \cap A')$: means all the area of $B$ not inside $A$.
$P(B)$ : The total area of $B$

So $P(B) - P(B \cap A') = 0.3 - 0.1 = 0.2  $
This is the area of intersection of $B$ and $A$.

So: $P(A) = 0.2 + P(A \cap B') = 0.2 + 0.2 = 0.4$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Is it okay now?

Comment: Looks good. Just note that you may want to be consistent and use "$A$" instead of "A" (similar for B) in the text (English sentences) as well.